# How to install code of gem and all its dependencies into one folder

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there any way to place all code for specific gem and it dependencies into one folder?

Comment: you need to mess with gem paths. see here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4405282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a gem and its dependencies to a specific folder as a one-off operation, you can use the `--install-dir` option to `gem install`:

```
gem install unicorn --install-dir my_folder
```

That would install unicorn, along with its dependencies kgio, rack, and raindrops, under my_folder.